# Am I doing my quantitative study on GitHub right?

Tags: hypothesis-testing

I am trying to do a small case study in 24 hours + change.

For a dataset, I'm using [GHTorrent.org](http://ghtorrent.org).

A general assumption about virtual work is that richer media leads to greater productivity. I have decided to focus on [GitHub](http://github.com) and to examine the effects of @mentions on issue resolution.

My hypothesis is that mentions are correlated with shorter time to issue resolution.

To see if this is true, I figure I can take a look at when an issue opened, when it closed, and how many mentions there were divided by how many comments there were.

Does this sound reasonable? I am a final-year master student and this is for a small assignment to get us familiar with writing scientific papers. Any advice is much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Seems like an interesting project, and that does seem reasonable, though with some caveats. So here's some thoughts I have.

First, you will encounter right-censoring, that is, there will be reported bugs that are still not resolved past the end of your dataset. You *absolutely cannot* just use the resolution time of resolved bugs and ignore the unresolved bugs - this will give biased results.

You could strictly enforce a set observation time (eg/ 1Y past the date the issue is opened); check the resolution status as a binary variable (resolved/not resolved) at the end of that period; and then run a logistic regression. However this potentially loses a lot of information, most obviously status after the cut-off period, and since things like number of mentions (and rate of mentions) during the observation period varies over time, you lose that information as well. Given that you only have 24 hours or so, I'd go with this.

Probably the "most correct" way to approach this is to treat it as a survival analysis problem, and use something like a cox proportional hazards model with time varying covariates; with bugs that are still not resolved at the end of your dataset set as censored. Your data would be something like one (binary - resolved/not resolved) observation per day/week/month per bug, and the relevant measured covariates for that day/week/month. I'm not too familiar with these, so I'll avoid further discussion.

Second, don't use a ratio as a explanatory variable when the two underlying variables are available! Use the two underlying variables and an interaction term instead. Consider the models
$Y = \beta_1A + \beta_2B+\beta_{12}AB$
$Y = \beta_{12}AB$
The second model is implied when you only utilize the ratio. There are quite a few good [answers](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=interaction%20main%20effect) to the question of excluding main effects while including an interaction.

Comment: I was going to comment but didn't because I didn't feel like my answer had much depth. Turns out that's exactly the case. I'd just like to add that, as a fellow masters student, phrases like "I figure" and "look at" are red flags to myself that I don't actually have any clue what I'm doing and need to think my project through much more carefully.